# Replace image source by id in Spring boot with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot

How do you change the source of an image in Spring boot because the normal JavaScript method does not work? This is my current code:

```
document.getElementById("img").src = "../static/images/hi.png";
th:src = "@{images/hi.png}";
```

Comment: is your id really "img"?

Comment: Yes. I only have one image.

Comment: Iam asking about id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("img").src = "/images/hi.png";
```